# Where is automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets result stored in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I am creating a UIView subclass that is using KVO to observe the contentOffset of a UITableView.  I'm using the contentOffset to resize subviews in my UIView subclass. automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is causing the scrollView.contentOffset to be -20, which is fine, but, in my UIView subclass' layoutSubviews, the scrollView.contentOffset is 0.  This is where I'm setting a property "initialContentOffset".  It is not until later that it is being set to -20.

Is there a way to be notified when this change happens? In other words, I need to be able to set the property "initalContentOffset" after the parent view (or whoever sets it) has made this adjustment.

I've checked the contentInset property of the scrollView and it is all 0s.

Below is the code and here is a link to download the project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tvv33pcrikrayz/ContentOffsetTest.zip?dl=0

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var someView: UIView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let aView = SomeView()
    aView.scrollView = self.tableView
    self.someView = aView

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60

 }
 }

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
}
```

SomeView.swift

```
import UIKit

private var ContentOffsetKVO = 0
private var ContentSizeKVO = 0

class SomeView: UIView {

var view: UIView!

public var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
    didSet {
        if let view = oldValue {
            removeKVO(scrollView: view)
        }

        if let view = scrollView {
            addKVO(scrollView: view)
            updateScrollPosition()
        }
    }
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "SomeView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    // 1. setup any properties here

    // 2. call super.init(frame:)
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    xibSetup()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // 1. setup any properties here

    // 2. call super.init(coder:)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    xibSetup()
}




deinit {
    if let scrollView = scrollView {
        removeKVO(scrollView: scrollView)
    }
}

// MARK: - KVO
private func removeKVO(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.removeObserver(
        self,
        forKeyPath: "contentSize",
        context: &ContentSizeKVO
    )
    scrollView.removeObserver(
        self,
        forKeyPath: "contentOffset",
        context: &ContentOffsetKVO
    )
}

func updateScrollPosition() {
    let offsetY: CGFloat = scrollView!.contentOffset.y

    print("updateScrollPosition (offsetY: \(offsetY))")
}

private func addKVO(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.addObserver(
        self,
        forKeyPath: "contentSize",
        options: [.initial, .new],
        context: &ContentSizeKVO
    )
    scrollView.addObserver(
        self,
        forKeyPath: "contentOffset",
        options: [.initial, .new],
        context: &ContentOffsetKVO
    )
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    switch keyPath {

    case .some("contentSize"), .some("contentOffset"):
            self.updateScrollPosition()

    default:
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }

     }

}
```

Comment: its on UIViewController

Comment: give some screenshot or code. make it easier to understand

Comment: Edited to add code and project link

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is set in the scrollView.contentInset after all - just at a later time.

```
 (lldb) po self.scrollView?.contentInset
▿ Optional<UIEdgeInsets>
  ▿ some : UIEdgeInsets
 - top : 20.0
- left : 0.0
- bottom : 0.0
- right : 0.0
```